# Show that $\frac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\in\mathcal R^1[-\pi,\pi]$ when $f(t), f(t)/t\in\mathcal R^1[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show below for $2\pi$-period function $f$:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|dt<\infty,\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(t)}{t}\right|dt<\infty \implies \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\right|dt<\infty$$

First, since $\dfrac{\sin 2t}{\sin t}$ is well-defined and bounded on $[-\pi,\pi]$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\right|dt<M_1\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(2t)}{\sin 2t}\right|dt$$
and since $f(2t)$ and $\sin 2t$ are both $\pi$-period function, we can restrict our focus on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ rather than $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then
$$M_1\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(2t)}{\sin 2t}\right|dt=2M_1\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left|\dfrac{f(2t)}{\sin 2t}\right|dt=M_1\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{\sin x}\right|dx$$
and we still must aware of $x=-\pi,0,\pi$ where denominator of the integrand is zero.

Near $x=0$, we can use
$$\left| \dfrac{1}{\sin t}\right|\leq\left|\dfrac{1}{t}\right|+\left|\dfrac{1}{t}-\dfrac{1}{\sin t}\right|$$
and using this inequality, I concluded that for some $\delta>0$
$$\int_{-\pi+\delta}^{\pi-\delta}\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{\sin x}\right|dx<\infty$$
but I still cannot show the convergence of the integration near $x=-\pi, \pi$.

How can I finish this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that near $t=0$, $\frac{t}{\sin \frac12t}$ is bounded. By using the fact that $\frac{f(t)}{t}\in \mathcal{R}^1[-\pi,\pi]$, one has, for small $\delta>0$
$$ \int_{-\delta}^\delta\bigg|\frac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\bigg|dt=\frac12\int_{-2\delta}^{2\delta}\bigg|\frac{f(t)}{\sin\frac12t}\bigg|dt=\frac12\int_{-2\delta}^{2\delta}\bigg|\frac{f(t)}{t}\bigg|\bigg|\frac{t}{\sin\frac12t}\bigg|dt<\infty.$$
Near $t=\pi$, for small $\delta>0$,
$$ \int_{\pi-\delta}^\pi\bigg|\frac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\bigg|dt=\int_{0}^{\delta}\bigg|\frac{f(2\pi-2t)}{\sin t}\bigg|dt=\int_{0}^{\delta}\bigg|\frac{f(-2t)}{\sin t}\bigg|dt=\int^{0}_{-\delta}\bigg|\frac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\bigg|dt<\infty.$$
Near $t=-\pi$, one can do the same trick. Collecting the above results, one has $\frac{f(2t)}{\sin t}\in\mathcal{R}^1[-\pi,\pi]$.